# X3D Calculating IndexedFaceSet coordIndex

Tags: html, x3d, x3dom

I would like to create an X3D arch through html, something like this: http://x3dgraphics.com/examples/X3dForAdvancedModeling/3DPrinting/UavBeehiveIndex.html

Since I have found that a cylinder shape is not enough to create an arch, I cannot define the thickness of an arch by setting its solid value to 'false'. I then found people use IndexedFaceSet coordIndex to create that shape. However, how do they calculate the coordIndex when the shape is getting very complex? As the shape as an example, the coordIndex is really long, I am not sure if there is any generator can help us get to that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can indeed do what you want with IndexedFaceSet, but you will probably need to create your own generator. I had the same issue with other shapes and started to create some generators for lines and surfaces in a d3 style, but I don't have one for your arch unfortunately.
It is [here: d3-x3dom-shape](https://github.com/fabid/d3-x3dom-shape) I hope it inspires you

Comment: You can try to build you model with Blender and then use the X3D Export of Blender. You can find an example here: https://www.x3dom.org/documentation/tutorials/blender-export/

Comment: indeed, for anything that is not a primitive shape you SHOULD use a dedicated software like Blender, MeshLab, Maya, Autodesk 3ds Max, etc. You can create the object there and export it to x3d, or any other supported formats..

Answer (score 1):

Large IndexedFaceSet definitions are indeed challenging to get correct unless you are very diligent.  Many modelers use a general 3D modeling tool to create complex shapes, then export to VRML or X3D meshes for publication.

Of note: the 'solid' field describes whether polygon geometry is rendered on one side or both sides.  solid='true' means solid like a brick, no internal structure, save rendering effort by just showing one side.  solid='false' ensures that both sides of a polygonal mesh are rendered, which is especially helpful is the normal orientation is opposite of what is expected.  Models with solid='true' are more efficient but might easily be invisible.

There are some good X3D arch models and prototypes online from a student project.  Test reports welcome, I can make any corrections or improvements needed.

- [X3D Example Archives: X3D for Advanced Modeling, Buildings](http://x3dgraphics.com/examples/X3dForAdvancedModeling/Buildings)
- [X3D Example Archives: X3D for Advanced Modeling, San Carlos Cathedral, San Carlos Cathedral](http://x3dgraphics.com/examples/X3dForAdvancedModeling/SanCarlosCathedral/SanCarlosCathedralIndex.html)

Incidentally the UAV Beehive example has moved and is now at

- [X3D Example Archives: X3D for Advanced Modeling, Additive Manufacturing, Uav Beehive](http://x3dgraphics.com/examples/X3dForAdvancedModeling/AdditiveManufacturing/UavBeehiveIndex.html)